# Validate fields before allowing a PDF form to be submitted

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, pdf, submit-button

I'm trying to create a PDF with a submit button that runs a custom JavaScript. The purpose of the code is to determine the value of one of the form fields and then run a math equation to determine if a warning should be displayed to the user or if they should be allowed to submit.

There are 3 scenarios I want to account for when the user clicks the submit button:

1. If the "CompletedValue" field is greater than or equal to 1,500,000 and the equation returns a value of less than 40. If this is true, the form should generate error message 1.
2. If the "CompletedValue" field is less than 1,500,000 and the equation returns a value of less than 25. If this is true, the form should generate error message 2.
3. Scenario 1 & 2 are false. If this is true, the form should generate an email.

To accomplish this I've written the following code, however, it is not working. When I click the Submit button, nothing happens.

```
var cV = this.getfield("CompletedValue").value;
var nV = cV - this.getfield("PresentValue").value;

var percentage = ( nV / cV ) * 100;

if (cV >= 1500000 && percentage < 40)
{
var error1= app.alert(errorMessage1,0,0,cTitle);
}

else if (cV < 1500000 && percentage < 25)
{
var error2= app.alert(errorMessage2,0,0,cTitle);
}

else 
{
this.mailDoc({bUI: true, cTo: cToAddr, cSubject: cSubLine, cMsg: cBody});
}
```

Any help on getting this to work would be appreciated.

Comment: what's the submit button look like? Chances are you are submitting the form instead of executing your code. When you click the submit button, execute this function, then have this function submit the form. Also you might like Angularjs's form field validations.

Comment: I only have one event set for the button. On mouseup the form runs this javascript.

Comment: Can you post the form somewhere?

Comment: You should be able to view/download it from here: https://www.scribd.com/document/333562277/Sample?secret_password=Gg2VNlDd7Y4FdbXNJM3r

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the Console? Ar the errorMessages definied somewhere?

Comment: I can't seem to open the console? Sorry, I'm very new to working with Adobe forms. I'm currently running Adobe Acrobate 9 Standard. Is the console only available on the professional version?

Comment: @MaxWyss yes, errorMessage1 & errorMessage2 are defined just above this section of the script. I've tried defining them both locally within the if statement and outside of the statement. Also, I've tested the error messages and the mail function separately and all 3 work. The problem appears to be in either the math or the if statement itself.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue simply by changing the case in the first two statements.

The case I used originally was:

```
var cV = this.getfield("CompletedValue").value;
```

This was corrected to:

```
var cV = this.getField("CompletedValue").value;
```

Note the capital 'F' in the getField.